# Select greater value than 0 if it exists, leave 0 if it is the only option

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**EDIT:** *I apologize for phrasing my question first time the wrong way ... I hope this one will make it clearer:*

I query the DB for quantities of a certain item (in my case item_id = 321) on all possible locations he might be having quantities on.

I am getting the following result:

```
item_location_id    item_def_loc_name   qty_per_location    item_id
8                   A08                 0.00                321                     
962                 POL_113             30.00               321         
5                   A05                 60.00               321
```

From these three given results (might be more or less in some cases) where we have one line containing zero qty result and couple others with greater quantities - I am aiming for the first "qty_per_location" that is greater than zero but lesser than the next quantity (in this example it is 30).

But for other items that have only one location assigned to them, query will be returning only one result line with qty_per_location = 0 - and I need it to be displayed because there is no greater quantities.

---

So if I have three quantities on stock for current item, like in the example below, the one with qty = 30 would be the desired one. But if I have only one location with 0 qty on it - then I should get zero as a result.

[image]

---

Hi once again - I ended up doing some fiddling and ended up using this as a possible solution:

```
DECLARE @QTY as decimal(5,2);

SELECT @QTY = (SELECT SUM(qty_per_location)
FROM [asm].[dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc]
where item_id = 321
group by item_id)

SELECT CASE (@QTY) WHEN 0 THEN

(Select top 1 IsNull(qty_per_location, 0) as qty
from [asm].[dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc]  -- change this to your table name 
Where qty_per_location = 0 and item_id = 321
Order by qty_per_location)

ELSE 

(Select top 1 IsNull(qty_per_location, 0) as qty
from [asm].[dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc]  -- change this to your table name 
Where qty_per_location > 0 and item_id = 321
Order by qty_per_location)

END
```

But, the trouble with this script is that I am unable to get [qty_per_location] to be displayed as header / column name above the qty result - I am getting "(No column name)". Also I am not able to get [item_location_id] column to show up beside [qty_per_location] as well ...

Please share your thoughts.
Thank you all!

Comment: what determines the order of your result set? `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourTable where qty_per_location > 0` needs an `ORDER BY` to be deterministic. Are there other columns you aren't listing? Also you said if you didn't care how many rows would be returned if the value was > 0, but then said you only wanted the second row returned.... why?

Comment: Please post code/sample data/results as text, not as image on another website. "i.stack.imgur.com is currently unable to handle this request."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the first quantity value in the table or 0 if there aren't any rows with positive value in the table:

```
Select IsNull(firstQty.qty_per_location, 0) as qty_per_location,
       tbl.item_location_id
from mdta_item-item_def_loc  tbl  
    left outer join (
        select top 1 tbl2.item_id, tbl2.qty_per_location, tbl2.item_location_id
        from mdta_item-item_def_loc  tbl2  
        Where tbl2.qty_per_location > 0 and tbl2.item_id = 321
        Order by tbl2.qty_per_location
    ) firstQty on tbl.item_id = firstQty.item_id and tbl.item_location_id = firstQty.item_location_id
Where tbl.item_id = 321
```

If you sort the query on the *qty_per_location*, you can get the lowest or the highest value too.

Comment: And what determines top 1? This value can change over time since you haven't specified an order by... and the OP asked for the "First Available Positive" alluding to an order.

Comment: I have explained in my answer that by adding the order the top 1 row can be managed. I don't see and date or timestamp field in the displayed schema, which suggests that system is tracking the latest quantity for each item per location. Top 1 can determine the lowest available quantity or the highest, depending on the sort order

Comment: sorting on `qty_per_location` may get desired results if the OP framed their question as poorly as i suspect, but it doesn't equal "first"

Comment: But in your query there is no order guranteed and thus result could even be 60 instead of 30 unless you specify a `order by`

Comment: There you go...I added to the sorting to the query to ease your mind :)

Comment: @Sparrow This solution displays the first value between zero and the next greater value indeed - but if there is a single line result with only qty_per_location = 0 it is not shown. _ I apologize for bad phrasing of the initial question - it might of lead you to this answer. _

Comment: I changed the query. Check it out and let me know if it works for you

Comment: @Rahul , Sparrow, scsimon, HoneyBadger... Guys, any suggestions over the newest edit (script)? Any opinion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I modified the query. Is this one not working either?

Comment: @Sparrow Unfortunately no for the time being ... Throws me Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 33 - Ambiguous column name 'item_id' and Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 25 Ambiguous column name 'qty_per_location'.
That's why I reverted to your previous query and combined it with the switch case. Now I am getting the right logic, 0 as a result if there is no greater values to be shown or else first greater value than zero if it exists... But now I am missing column name for [qty_per_location] - only "(No column name)" is displayed, and I would like to see column [item_location_id] beside the qty.

Comment: @nexus.so: Sorry. I fixed the Ambiguous column name error. Try it again.

Comment: @Sparrow Works like a charm this time! Last thing - is it possible to display location id in the column next to the qty result it belongs to? Thank you man a gazillion times for this sorcery! ^_^

Comment: @nexus.so: You are welcome! Isn't tbl.item_location_id what you are asking for? I have already added it to the query. Also, I'm a lady :)

Comment: Dear @Sparrow, I apologize for gender mix up - it was unclear from your nick right away :) Glad to see a lady conquering IT world one script at a time and so generously sharing knowledge! I've tried taming your script to my needs, but was unable on some edge cases I faced during testing - so I ended up using small IF-ELSE statement that worked in my case ... Nevertheless I would like to thank you tremendously for your time and effort put in pointing me in the right direction. Stay awesome and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank to all people of good will, that helped me solve this SQL puzzle of mine by spending their time to point me on my way :)

This is what I adopted and ended up using, that satisfied my requirement:

```
DECLARE @QTY as decimal(5,2);
SET @QTY = 0;   

IF @QTY < (SELECT SUM(qty_per_location)
FROM [asm].[dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc]
where item_id = 321
group by item_id)

Select top 1 qty_per_location, [item_def_loc_name]
from [dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc] 

inner join [dbo].[mdta_item_def_loc] on
[dbo].[mdta_item_def_loc].[item_def_loc_id] = [dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc].[item_location_id]

where item_id = 321 
order by qty_per_location desc

ELSE

Select top 1 qty_per_location, [item_def_loc_name]
from [dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc] 

inner join [dbo].[mdta_item_def_loc] on
[dbo].[mdta_item_def_loc].[item_def_loc_id] = [dbo].[mdta_item-item_def_loc].[item_location_id]

where item_id = 321
```

Best regards y'all!